# Can't change trendline style in GGPlot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot three trendlines on a black and white scatterplot. This is the code I am using:

```
BlackWhite<-ggplot(plot.hg,aes(x=ToeArchTemp,y=DF..N.,group=Condition,colour=Condition))
  +geom_point(aes(shape=Condition,color=Condition),size=2)
  +geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)
  +scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 1, 3))
  +scale_color_manual(values=c("black","black","black"))
  +theme_bw()+scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid","dotted","twodash"))
  +scale_size_manual(values=c(1,1.5,1))
```

The three lines are all showing up as solid black lines - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define the mapping in the "geom_smooth()" function.  Try something like: `geom_smooth(mapping=aes(linetype=Condition, color=Condition), method="lm", se=FALSE)`

Comment: If you don't have anything mapped to `linetype=` in your `aes()` then the `scale_linetype_manual()` isn't going to do anything. Same goes for size. You need to have a mapping in order for the scales to work.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked Dave2e